# How to see interactive output when running nmap from a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, nmap

I'm trying to run nmap from a Bash script, in a way so that when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed it should give some output, as happens when running directly from the commandline.

When calling a few different `nmap` scans from a Bash script, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not show the time remaining as it would if I ran it directly from the command line.

An example line from my script:

```
nmap -T4 -iL input.txt -PN -sS -oA tcp_top_1000
```

Running `nmap` like this via the command line, and then hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> results in this type of output:

```
$ nmap -T4 -iL input.txt -PN -sS -oA tcp_top_1000

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-10-18 01:21 EDT
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (0 up), 1 undergoing ARP Ping Scan
Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. Timing: About 0.00% done
Stats: 0:00:01 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (0 up), 1 undergoing ARP Ping Scan
Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. Timing: About 0.00% done
Stats: 0:00:02 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (0 up), 1 undergoing ARP Ping Scan
Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. Timing: About 0.00% done
```

However running that same `nmap` command in a shell script inhibits it's ability to do the above.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Try to specify `-i` option in she-bang. It may help you.

Comment: Please provide us with an example of what you're doing.

Comment: @slm, I did provide an example. Calling nmap to do a scan from a script. The scan type or parameters don't matter.

Comment: Yeah that's not enough, please provide a couple of lines from the script.

Comment: @slm are you familiar with nmap? Really, the command doesn't matter, even "nmap host" will return output when enter is pressed while it is running. Besides, the problem isn't specific to a particular program. "nmap -sU host" is a fine example of a line from the script..

Comment: probably @sim is asking for a copy/paste example of your script or command line, so that they can reproduce it...

Comment: Yes the script, I could careless about the actual tools and yes I'm familiar with nmap. Please read my original comment where I asked for a couple of lines from the **script**!

Comment: Also I wouldn't waste your time asking you for things if I didn't think it was relevant. I'm trying to help you solve your issue and the normal behavior is that when you put commands in a script and run it, their output is displayed, so obviously something is not normal here!

Comment: @slm output is being displayed from the script, just not the "interactive" output that is shown when you press enter in nmap. I've included a line from the script. It purely consists of about 6 lines like this with different nmap parameters.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill I get that, but as I said the script contains only nmap commands, nothing else. No variables, conditions or anything. I didn't see how the parameters to nmap were relevant.